# Need help simulating program that simulates a thief stealing televisions

Tags: java, arrays, class, data-structures, for-loop

Picked up a Java Textbook now. Actually trying to learn the language again.

There is a very interesting piece of code in this book that entails a class called House that simulates a thief stealing TVs from people's houses (which are also classes).

Only problem is I can't seem to figure out how to modify my array to change the number of Houses that the thief collects. It's hard to explain but here is my code right now. I'm completely lost at the moment. I really can't understand how arrays work which is bugging the hell out of me. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class House {
  public int nHDTVs;
  public House pFriend;
  public House(int nParameter, House friendParameter)
  {
    nHDTVs = nParameter;
    pFriend = friendParameter;
  }
  public void steal(House thiefsHouse, House firstVictim)
  {
    int nTVsStolen = 0;
    int victimNumber = 0;
    for(int i =0; i<victimNumber; i++)
    {
     nTVsStolen = nTVsStolen + array[i];
    }
    //nTVsStolen = nTVsStolen + 
    /*for(i=1;i>10;i++)
    {
      //stuff
    }*/
    //thiefsHouse nHDTVs = n


    System.out.println("Victim " + (victimNumber+1) + " " + "lives at " + firstVictim);
    System.out.println("Victim " + (victimNumber+2) + " " + "lives at " + firstVictim.pFriend);
 System.out.println("I've just stolen " + 0 + " TVs from the House at " + null);

    thiefsHouse.nHDTVs = thiefsHouse.nHDTVs + nTVsStolen;
  }
  public static void main(String dfgasdfwe[]) {
    int nHouses;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many houses should the thief steal from?");
    nHouses = keyboard.nextInt();
    House array[] = new House[nHouses];
    array[nHouses - 1] = new House(3, null);
    for(int i = nHouses - 2; i>=0; i--)
    {
      array[i] = new House( i , array[i+1]);
    }
    House thiefsHouse = array[0];
    //pFriend nHDTVs[victimNumber] = 0;
    thiefsHouse.steal(thiefsHouse, thiefsHouse.pFriend);
    System.out.println("I now have " + thiefsHouse.nHDTVs + " TV sets. HA HA.");

  }
}
```

Comment: "Need help simulating program that simulates a thief stealing televisions" - wow, social modelling at work! Hmmmm, I need a new TV....

Comment: I thought that this was clever myself. I was surprised seeing something like this in a textbook haha

Comment: It doesn't look like the scope of your array[] variable is correct. You call array[] in your steal function without instantiating it as a class variable.

Comment: Secondly, my guess is that you want to iterate over the houses, going from house to house and stealing the tv in the house. What I would to is to accept the array of houses as an argument in a static steal function, and iterate over that list, calling the steal function on each house. What the example might be trying to teach is abstraction for block operations.

Comment: Thanks, man. Much appreciated. I've basically been staring at my screen for the last 3 hours trying to figure this out. Figured I'd come here to ask for help. But are you saying I should put the array as a class variable and then return it into the steal method? Or make the array in the steal method?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Misuse_case

Comment: try Mark's response first, he might be seeing things I'm missing-- like i'm not sure what pFriend is supposed to do. Posting what the question states verbatim will help if you're still having trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is fundamentally here

```
int nTVsStolen = 0;
int victimNumber = 0;
for(int i =0; i<victimNumber; i++)
{
 nTVsStolen = nTVsStolen + array[i];
}
```

The first problem is that the code won't compile because `array` is defined in main and not visible in this scope.  Next up array is of type House and so can't work with the + operator.

`victimNumber` is always zero and so the loop never executes.

Maybe replace it with

```
while(nHDTVs > 0)
{
 nHDTVs--;
 nTVsStolen++;
 System.out.println("I stole a TV from this Victim: " + toString());
}
```

Comment: That really helped a lot actually. I got my code to run perfectly after a few more minutes of tweaking it. Thanks.

Comment: Cheers.  Remember to mark the question as answered if everything is squared away and working.